# How to get the locale of a Firefox extension with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have spent lots of time trying to find a way to get the locale of Firefox extension within the extension's Javascript code. The closes I am general.useragent.locale, which I think holds the preferred localization, but Firefox's user language can be totally different.

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to ask: XUL or SDK add-on?

Comment: XUL I guess. I mean, its a regular extension that attaches a button to Firefox Chrome and performs some action on button click

Comment: Do you use XUL overlays? Then it is XUL. Do you use the Add-on Builder or the SDK `cfx`? Then it's an SDK add-on.

Comment: Oh now I see the difference, then it is definitely XUL. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When trying to query XUL packages, have a look at [`nsIXULChromeRegistry.getSelectedLocale(package)`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/chrome/public/nsIChromeRegistry.idl#54).

Sample (querying the locale for the global/toolkit package):

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/chrome/chrome-registry;1"]
  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIXULChromeRegistry)
  .getSelectedLocale('global'); // e.g "en-US"
```

SDK add-ons could use the following to determine their own locale, although it should be noted that this API is marked "unstable".

```
require("sdk/l10n/core").locale
```

SDK add-ons may still use `nsIXULChromeRegistry.getSelectedLocale(package)` to query other add-ons or the browser via the [`chrome`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) module.

Comment: Oops, sorry... I edited the answer. Usually most code uses `Cc = Components.classes; Ci = Components.interfaces`, but it is not defined by default.

Comment: Just a small update: "require("sdk/l10n/core").locale" no longer works. The new way seems to be "require("sdk/l10n/locale").getPreferedLocales();" which returns an array.